# Create InternetExplorer object in VB6 that is not a child process

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6

We are creating an InternetExplorer window like this:

```
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
Set Browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

We've noticed that if there is an external IE window already opened, then the browser created in our application is created as a child process of that IE process.  If there is no IE window already opened, then the browser our application creates is it's own parent process.

We need to ensure that the browser our application creates is *always* a top-level parent process, and not the child of another IE process.  Anyone know of a way to do that?

To add a little more information, this first image shows the IE processes that are present if we:

1. First start our application, which in turn creates a browser window.
2. Then start another browser (IE) externally.

So there are two browsers running.  Each has two processes (the *32 processes are child processes of the other ones).[image: App starts first]

Then, if we do things in the other order:

1. Start external browser.
2. Start our application, which then creates another browser window.

The picture then looks like this:
[image: External browser starts first]

In this case, the browser our application creates has been created as a child process of the first (external) browser.  This is what we need to avoid.

Comment: so you need to start a new session? sorry, haven't understand if you are using vb6 or vba...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you use `CreateObject(...)` then you should use:

```
Dim Browser As Object ' not As InternetExplorer
```

Second, the answer is NOT, because it's your application it self that create the child process (Browser).

If you want a top-level process, then dont'use your application, but in this case you can't 'manage' the process, from your application.